# Spring roo doesn't work after upgrade, always ask for version

Tags: spring-roo

I upgraded the spring too suite (2.8.1.RELEASE -> 2.9.1.RELEASE) and spring roo (1.2.0.M1 -> 1.2.1.RELEASE). I deleted all the *.aj files and changed "@RooRepositoryJpa" to "@RooJpaRepository" and "@RooEntity" to "@RooJpaActiveRecord".

After I made the changes and spring roo doesn't work, even the hint command.

Here is the error:

```
    ____  ____  ____  
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \ 
  / /_/ / / / / / / / 
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /  
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.2.1.RELEASE [rev 6eae723]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo> hint
Version is required
roo>
```

Please give me some advice and help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [this problem](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3096). Review content of your "pom.xml".